# How to redirect in Asynchronous Servlet?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-3.0, sendasynchronousrequest

According to [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867311/using-asynchronous-servlets-and-the-behaviour-of-dispatch-and-complete-metho), I understand a `Request` could be dispatch forward to another servlet in one Asynchronous Servlet which also makes container to call `complete()` and trigger another Servlet or JSP automatically.

But, what if I want to redirect the page under async Servlet? Should I call `complete()` and `response.redirect("")` both? do we have any example of redirection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in this situation is that give specific json response to client (browser) using response.getWriter.write(jsonObject) and in JavaScript you write code for changing the location i.e location.assign("/newPage").

Comment: Care to elaborate on your answer?

Comment: @ZishanMohsin thanks for your answer. so there is noway to redirect the page at server side in this case?

Comment: You can redirect the request to another page but don't send that request to a view page, otherwise client who sent the asynch request will get html code in response.